# How to remove second largest element in a list in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have created a program to remove first smallest element but I dont how to do for second largest:

```
withoutBiggest (x:xs) =
   withoutBiggestImpl (biggest x xs) [] (x:xs)
     where
       biggest :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> a
       biggest big [] = big
       biggest big (x:xs) =
         if x < big then
           biggest x xs
         else
           biggest big xs
       withoutBiggestImpl :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
       withoutBiggestImpl big before (x:xs) =
         if big == x then
           before ++ xs
         else
             withoutBiggestImpl big (before ++ [x]) xs
```

Comment: Is it an ordered list?

Comment: Sort the list, find the second-largest element, and remove that element from the original list. Lots of edge cases to consider: What if the list is empty? What if it has only one element? What if it contains duplicate entries of the second-largest element? What if all the elements are the same?

Comment: Agreed with @MarkSeemann, many oustanding questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.

```
Prelude> let list = [10,20,100,50,40,80]
Prelude> let secondLargest = maximum $ filter (/= (maximum list)) list
Prelude> let result = filter (/= secondLargest) list
Prelude> result
[10,20,100,50,40]
Prelude>
```

Comment: @MERCURYEDITS that's because the list is empty in `secondLargest`.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility, surely not the best one.

```
import Data.Permute (rank)

x = [4,2,3]
ranks = rank (length x) x -- this gives [2,0,1]; that means 3 (index 1) is the second smallest
```

Then:

```
 [x !! i | i <- [0 .. length x -1], i /= 1]
```

Hmm.. not very cool, let me some time to think to something better please and I'll edit my post.

## EDIT

Moreover my previous solution was wrong. This one should be correct, but again not the best one:

```
import Data.Permute (rank, elems, inverse)

ranks = elems $ rank (length x) x
iranks = elems $ inverse $ rank (length x) x

>>> [x !! (iranks !! i) | i <- filter (/=1) ranks]
[4,2]
```

An advantage is that this preserves the order of the list, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that removes the n smallest elements from your list:

```
import Data.List

deleteN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
deleteN _ []     = []
deleteN i (a:as)
   | i == 0    = as
   | otherwise = a : deleteN (i-1) as

ntails :: Int -> [a] -> [(a, Int)] -> [a]
ntails 0 l _ = l
ntails n l s = ntails (n-1) (deleteN (snd $ head s) l) (tail s)

removeNSmallest :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeNSmallest n l = ntails n l $ sort $ zip l [0..]
```

EDIT:

If you just want to remove the 2nd smallest element:

```
deleteN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
deleteN _ []     = []
deleteN i (a:as)
   | i == 0    = as
   | otherwise = a : deleteN (i-1) as

remove2 :: [a] -> [(a, Int)] -> [a]
remove2 [] _  = []
remove2 [a] _ = []
remove2 l s = deleteN (snd $ head $ tail s) l

remove2Smallest :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
remove2Smallest l = remove2 l $ sort $ zip l [0..]
```

Comment: Isn’t `deleteN` equal to `take`?

Comment: No, `deleteN` removes an item at the nth position. `take` takes the first n elements

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear if the OP is looking for the biggest (as the name `withoutBiggest` implies) or what. In this case, one solution is to combine the `filter :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` and `maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a` functions from the `Prelude`.

```
withoutBiggest l = filter (/= maximum l) l
```

Comment: A possible problem with this solution is that we would get the  empty list if the list is constant. But the OP didn't give the precisions on such particular situations, so we can't really reply...

Comment: Well that's a consequence of the problem definition. If all the duplicates of the biggest element have to be removed, an empty list is the right output in that case. It doesn't seem a "problem" to me.

Comment: That's a way to see the issue, but what about the OP ? Maybe he has another idea in mind, and we dont know. That's not a criticism about your answer. I just claim we miss some "parameters" to provide an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the biggest elements by first finding it and then filtering it:

```
withoutBiggest :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
withoutBiggest [] = []
withoutBiggest xs = filter (/= maximum xs) xs
```

You can then remove the second-biggest element in much the same way:

```
withoutSecondBiggest :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
withoutSecondBiggest xs =
  case withoutBiggest xs of
    [] -> xs
    rest -> filter (/= maximum rest) xs
```

Assumptions made:

- You want each occurrence of the second-biggest element removed.
- When there is zero/one element in the list, there isn't a second element, so there isn't a second-biggest element. Having the list without an element that isn't there is equivalent to having the list.
- When the list contains only values equivalent to `maximum xs`, there also isn't a second-biggest element even though there may be two or more elements in total.
- The `Ord` type-class instance implies a total ordering. Otherwise you may have multiple maxima that are not equivalent; otherwise which one is picked as the biggest and second-biggest is not well-defined.